# Very long datestamp format

Tags: datestamp

Need to parse logs with datestamp in format longer than traditional Unix timestamp 
    localTime="636597250599883050" utcTime="636597142599883050" 
Regualar Unix timestamp to compare

> > > time.time()
> > >           1525193621.900381
> > >       time.gmtime(1525193621.900381)
> > >           time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=16, tm_min=53, tm_sec=41, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=121, tm_isdst=0)

Any ideas how it should be converted to ms since 1/1/1970 ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It is .Net Datetime tick format. The difference with Unix datestamp is start date is 00:00:00 1/1/0001  instead of midnight 1/1/1970 
[Converter](https://www.venea.net/web/net_ticks_datetime_converter)